# Linear regression on split data in R

Tags: r, aggregate, lm

I want to make groups of data where measurements are done in multiple `Year` on the same species at the same `Lat` and `Long`. Then, I want to run linear regression on all those groups (using `N` as dependent variable and `Year` as independent variable).

Practice dataset:

```
  Species Year Lat Long   N
1       1 1999   1    1   5
2       1 2001   2    1   5
3       2 2010   3    3   4
4       2 2010   3    3   2
5       2 2011   3    3   5
6       2 2012   3    3   8
7       3 2007   8    7 -10
8       3 2019   8    7 100
9       2 2000   1    1   5
```

First, I averaged data where multiple measurements were done in the same `Year` on the same `Species` at the same `latitude` and `longitude` . Then, I split data based on `Lat`, `Long` and `Species`. However, this still groups rows together where `Lat`, `Long` and `Species` are not equal `($ '4')`. Furthermore, I want to remove `$'1'`, since I only want to use data where multiple measurements are done over a number of `Year`. How do I do this?

```
Data <- read.table("Dataset.txt", header = TRUE)
Agr_Data <- aggregate(N ~ Lat + Long + Year + Species, data = Data, mean)
Split_Data <- split(Agr_Data, Agr_Data$Lat + Agr_Data$Long + Agr_Data$Species)
Regression_Data <- lapply(Split_Data, function(Split_Data) lm(N~Year, data = Split_Data) )


Split_Data

$`3`
  Lat Long Year Species N
1   1    1 1999       1 5

$`4`
  Lat Long Year Species N
2   2    1 2001       1 5
3   1    1 2000       2 5

$`8`
  Lat Long Year Species N
4   3    3 2010       2 3
5   3    3 2011       2 5
6   3    3 2012       2 8

$`18`
  Lat Long Year Species   N
7   8    7 2007       3 -10
8   8    7 2019       3 100
```

Desired output:

```
  Lat Long Species   Coefficients
    3    3       2   2.5
    8    7       3   9.167
```

Comment: Hi, your example could easily be reproducible if you use dput().

Comment: my apologies, quite new to R. Here is the dput output.


structure(list(Species = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L
), Year = c(1999L, 2001L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2007L, 
2019L, 2000L), Lat = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 1L), Long = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 1L), N = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 
-10L, 100L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
# 1. Import data: 

df <- structure(list(Species = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L ),
                     Year = c(1999L, 2001L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2007L, 2019L, 2000L),
                     Lat = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 1L),
                     Long = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 1L),
                     N = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, -10L, 100L, 5L)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L ))

# 2. Aggregate data: 

df <- aggregate(N ~ Lat + Long + Year + Species, data = df, mean)

# 3. Concatenate vecs to create grouping vec: 

df$grouping_var <- paste(df$Species, df$Lat, df$Long, sep = ", ")

# 4. split apply combine lm:  

coeff_n <- as.numeric(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$grouping_var), 

                          function(x){

                           ifelse(nrow(x) > 1, coef(lm(N ~ Species+Lat+Long, data = x)), NA)

                          }

                        )

                      )

                    )


# 5.  Create a dataframe of coeffs: 

coeff_df <- data.frame(cbind(grouping_var = unique(df$grouping_var), coeff_n = coeff_n))

# 6. Merge the dataframes together: 

df <- merge(df, coeff_df, by = "grouping_var", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I do this, I also get an output for locations where a species is sampled once (for example lat = 1, long = 1, species = 1, Year = 1999). I wish to exclude those. And is it possible to get the unstandardised coefficients instead of predictions (change in N per year)? 
I now included the desired output in the post.

Comment: @maarvd please see the edited code above. If it is suitable please accept the answer and give it an upvote ;)

Comment: Hi! Ran the code, but it gives 5.3333333 and 45 as coefficients respectively. When I manually calculate it, it should be 2.5 and 9.167.

Comment: was the code correct or did it require adjustments ?

Comment: Hi! It did not give me the coefficients (2.5 and 9.167, see desired output in the post). That adjustment would be much appreciated :)